# How to get selected value from a dropdown after it has been disabled after a selection

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have this code below. Everything will be disabled after a selection.

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="javascript:this.disabled = 'disabled';">
<option value="dropdown">Pls select one
<option value="apple">Apple
<option value="oragne">Orange
<option value="grapes">Grapes
</select>
```

But when I hit submit, the value for the "dropdown" is not being passed. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled form controls don't get submitted. This is normal behaviour.

One work around is to copy the selected value to a hidden input that *would* get submitted.

(I really don't recommend disabling a select on change though - what if the user accidentally clicked the wrong thing? What if they were trying to select with the keyboard?)

(And as another aside, you don't need `javascript:` in inline event attributes.)

EDIT: How to implement the hidden input? Well, give the hidden input the name that your server-side code expects (and remove the `name` attribute from the select element):

```
<input type="hidden" name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
```

And then your `onchange` attribute would be something like:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('dropdown').value=this.value; this.disabled=true;">
```

Comment: So how will I pass the selected value to a hidden input? Thanks! :)

Comment: OK, I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Also: `this.form.inputName.value = this.value`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your selected option from your dropdown will not be passed its because you had your dropdown disabled. maybe thats the reason why. try not disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems disabled selection does not submit by default.

You can add another hidden selection element. And use script to make choice to submit.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to disable a control, then submit its value. If you want the value submitted, don't disable it.

Anyhow, one option is to enable the control before submitting:

```
<form ... onsubmit="this.dropdown.disabled = false;">
```

Now you don't have to copy the value anywhere and the value will be submitted whether the control is disabled or not.